# remove duplicate login link in MediaWiki using Shibboleth plugin

Tags: mediawiki, shibboleth

I've added shibboleth authentication (ShibAuthPlugin 1.2.3)  to a MediaWiki site (mw 1.17).  That turned out to be pretty straightforward, but I now have another related problem:  I have two login links.  I want only the Shibboleth login link to be available.

I can alter the CSS to hide the unwanted link, but that only makes it invisible.  I want to disable it.  The documented ways of disabling login links disables all login links.  I'm new to MediaWiki and would expect to be able to make this change in the configuration and not have to hack the code to get what I want.

Perhaps someone familiar with MediaWiki can tell me if such a configuration setting exists, or if code modification is the best practice for solving this kind of problem.

Thank you in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

To just remove the login link, I suspect [this FAQ entry](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aFAQ#How_do_I_remove_the_.22Create_an_Account_or_Login.22_link_at_the_top_right_of_the_screen.3F) may help; it seems to be more or less how the [Shibboleth auth extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aShibboleth_Authentication) does its own login/logout link mangling.  For convenience, let me copy the code here:

```php
$wgHooks['PersonalUrls'][] = 'lfRemoveLoginLink';
function lfRemoveLoginLink( &$personal_urls, $title ) {
        unset( $personal_urls['login'] );
        unset( $personal_urls['anonlogin'] );
        unset( $personal_urls['createaccount'] );
        return true;
}
```

If you want to completely disable local login/logout, even if the user deliberately goes to `Special:UserLogin`, [this solution](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk%3aHttpAuth#Disabling_Special%3aUserLogin_and_Special%3aUserLogin_.3B_removal_of_login_and_logout_links) might do the trick.  Again, let me copy the relevant part of the code below:

```php
function LessSpecialPages(&$list) {
  unset( $list['Userlogout'] );
  unset( $list['Userlogin'] );
  return true;
}
$wgHooks['SpecialPage_initList'][]='LessSpecialPages';
```